# System.AccessViolationException when calling function from unmanaged DLL using DLLImport

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, dllimport

I'm trying to call a function from a C++ DLL using DLLImport (P/Invoke) and I keep getting a System.AccessViolationException error when I call it. Note that I other functions to work.

Declaration of the DLLImport function:

```c
[DllImport("DocProc.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern uint getDPpupTrkBaseConfigPath(DPHandle hdl, StringBuilder str, uint strsize);
```

Usage:

```c
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);
                getDPpupTrkBaseConfigPath(handle, sb, (uint)sb.Capacity);
```

DPHandle: (note that it works in other functions)

```c
public struct DPHandle
        {
            public uint Size;
            public IntPtr UserHandle;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string DeviceName;
            public uint DeviceTypeId;
            public uint DeviceState;
            public uint OpenFlags;
            public IntPtr Reserved1;
        };
```

C++:

```cpp
BPS_PROPL getDPpupTrkBaseConfigPath(DPHandle hdl, char *str, unsigned long strsize);
```

(Note BPS_PROPL = unsigned long)

DPHandle:

```cpp
struct DocProcHandle {
    unsigned long Size;//sizeof(DocProcHandle)
    void* UserHandle;
    const char* DeviceName;
    unsigned long DeviceTypeId;
    unsigned long DeviceState;
    unsigned long OpenFlags;
    void* Reserved1;
};
typedef struct DocProcHandle *DPHandle;
```

Again, when I try to call the function that exception shows up. I tried looking at other answers but can't figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Can you try it without the `StringBuilder` and use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` in stead? Also changing `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string DeviceName;` to `public IntPtr DeviceName` and see if you still get an access violation. Have you also verified that `__cdecl` is your standard calling convention?

Comment: Try getting pointer to the structure and pass it instead passing the structure itself

Comment: I'm not sure if using IntPtr instead of StringBuilder will work because I want the C++ to fill a string in the StringBuilder. And again DPHandle works in other functions so I don't think that's the case here. And yes I have verified.

Comment: @SohaibJundi Okay

Comment: That worked! Changing the struct to IntPtr worked! Thanks!

Comment: Is a long 32 bits or 64 bits?  c++ you have ling but in c# you have int.  A UnmanagedType.LPStr is a byte[] terminated with a '\0' which in c++ is char *str.  In c# you have a StringBuilder which must be converted to a LPStr.  You use a byte[] in c# because in c# a char is a class that is two bytes wide (not one byte).

Comment: @jdweng in C++ on Windows `long` is 32 bits. The string code is fine, `StringBuilder` is exactly what you use when you want to allocate a character array that will be populated by the callee in a pinvoke method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the C++ code, you have:

```
typedef struct DocProcHandle *DPHandle;
```

This means that `DPHandle` is a pointer to the struct. But in your C# code you pass the the struct by value.

The simplest way to achieve that is to change the declaration of the first argument of your pinvoke code from

```
DPHandle hdl
```

to

```
[In] ref DPHandle hdl
```

Comment: That might work, but I have already fixed it by changing to IntPtr. Thanks though

Comment: Sure you can do it that way, but it's more code that way. Anyway, this answer explains the problem, in case you want to understand it.